# Bouncy Castle - Obsolete LegacyTlsClient

Tags: .net, bouncycastle

I would like to create a TlsClient with Bouncy Castle with following code

```
public SecureTcpClient(string host, int port)
    : this(host, port, new LegacyTlsClient(new AlwaysValidVerifyer()))
{

}
```

This class LegacyTlsClient is however obsolete but I don't know Bouncy Castle much enough to fix this thing. Which class should be used to replace LegacyTlsClient.

Comment: There's a DefaultTlsClient that is not deprecated, but it looks like you have to implement it since it's abstract. And there's a PSKTlsClient and an SRPTlsClient, both of which are abstract as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use DefaultTlsClient class directly, like this:

```
class TlsClient : DefaultTlsClient {
    public override TlsAuthentication GetAuthentication() {
        return new CustomTlsAuthentication();
    }
}

class CustomTlsAuthentication : TlsAuthentication {
    public TlsCredentials GetClientCredentials(CertificateRequest certificateRequest) {
        // return client certificate here if necessary
        return null;
    }

    public void NotifyServerCertificate(Certificate serverCertificate) {
        // validate server certificate here
    }
}
```